# Running qcollectiongenerator during application compile process

Tags: qt, qmake

I've been working on a program called RoboJournal for a long time. The next release has full documentation included; Whenever the user presses F1 or clicks the Help item in the RoboJournal program, the help file is displayed in Qt Assistant (way classier than simply opening a browser window to some online documentation).

In its base form, the documentation consists of lots of loose HTML and image files included in the source package. These loose files are supposed to be compiled into a QCH compiled help file and QHC collection file during build time so Qt Assistant can display the documentation properly.  On Windows, this was fairly easy because I was able to write a batch script to automate the entire build process (including compiling the documentation and moving the output files to the right place).

On Linux, it's a bit more complicated. True, I could write a Bash or Perl script that compiles the documentation along with the rest of the program but I have no guarantee that the people who will eventually create my app's Debian packages from the source package I give them will use the script. The source package is used to create all the Debian packages so everything has to work flawlessly with the standard build procedure (or the source package is worthless). Therefore, I need the compile process to produce the same results whether the user runs the script or not. As it is now, the user has to build and install the documentation manually. Surely there's some way to automate this.

Is it possible to have Qmake add instructions to run qcollectiongenerator to the makefile (in order to build my application's help files) so it gets handled properly during the "make" step? That way, the QHC and QCH files will be ready to install to their proper locations (in my case, /usr/share/doc/robojournal-0.4.1) along with everything else when the user runs "make install". I've considered compiling the QCH and QHC files in advance and providing them in the source package but the whole point of building from source is to be able to re-create the entire app from its base components.

I know I probably have to add additional instructions to my .PRO file but I’m not sure what or how. I've found something that looks promising (http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-49484.html) and gives me hope that it's possible for Qmake to do what I need but I’m not sure how applicable those instructions are to my situation. Do I have to create a PRI file just for this or can I add the instructions directly to the main project file?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the `QMAKE_POST_LINK` variable:

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK  += build_help.sh
```

P.S.

> I have no guarantee that the people who will eventually create my
>   app's Debian packages from the source package I give them will use the
>   script.

I think this is really not your problem :) It's up to them to properly build the package.